# Gaining the Quicken Enchantment

Tags: low-fantasy

This question concerns the Quicken enchantment, which is gained from Runnark. Runnark are quick, agile, and deadly solo predators, a small dinosaur (like Indoraptor) that through convergent evolution resembles a cheetah. It's about the same size, it runs on four legs and is essentially a faster Komodo Dragon; hungry, aggressive, fierce, but with the dogged persistence of a wolf and the speed of a cheetah. (There's more; they can run up walls and even on ceilings, sprint so fast they seem to teleport, and have *really* tough hides to protect them from the heat and friction created by their high-paced life, which makes them impervious to arrows, swords, daggers, and spears.)

But how can it have both? Aren't those two mutually exclusive? No, because Runnark have:

1. Better Respiratory and Cardiovascular Systems

Like archosaurs, Runnark have air sacs instead of lungs, which combined with their very mammalian blood is a cardiorespiratory combo better than anything else on Earth. They get more oxygen with every breath than anything else, and they don't get winded running at full speed.

2. Caloric Support
   Runnark are magically connected to the Sun, so they absorb heat and light for additional energy. Since they naturally absorb the heat generated by their sustained running, they stay at optimum temperature and don't have to worry about overheating.

The trouble is, this makes gaining a Runnark's enchantment *very* difficult. They can outrun a man on a horse with ease, they're too fast and agile to easily trap or contain, and their tough hides make them nigh-invincible. This is even more difficult when one considers that there are only *three* methods by which one can gain a monster's enchantment:

1. being alive inside it when it is killed,
2. killing the monster *personally* (with their bare hands or feet, for example; your own body must be the weapon that kills it),
3. or killing the monster with a weapon incorporating one's own body (like a spear tipped with a spearhead made of your own bone, or a club covered in your baby teeth).

Thus, my question is: **What Is The Most Efficient Way To Gain The Quicken Enchantment?**

**Specifications:**

1. By "efficient," I mean most effective, the easiest to pull off, requiring the least amount of labor and resources to perform. This method (or methods, if you want to be thorough) should fit the criteria for method 1, 2, or 3; it should be a method of killing an evolved Chomper that will get the user the said monster's Enchantment.
2. Said methods should be **feasible for medieval Europeans;** something they can actually come up with and execute.

Answer (score 5):

**Baby Runmarks.**

1. Find Runmark nest.
2. Steal eggs.
3. Wait for them to hatch.
4. Kill little Runmarks as they hatch.  With your bare hands.  Maybe teeth.  Other body parts as circumstances warrant.  It will be a party!

Comment: Very good answer; I'm surprised I didn't think of it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Kill them in WINTER.

Cold-blooded reptiles can not regulate their internal temperature. Usually, they hibernate. So you wait for winter, embark on a hunting trip when the temperature is below zero.

Get in the cave, grab the cheeta-sized reptile that will be in deep hibernation. And break its neck.

Even if the monster awakens, its muscles will be almost frozen, depending if it behaves like the frogs that actually became frozen in winter. Then presents no danger to you.

Comment: This is a great answer, Runnark do hibernate in winter, though they are more dinosaur than anything else (I edited the OP upon realizing this). This is due to their connection to light and heat, and the fact that winter tends to be cold and dark.